# How to compare locale String's in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

yeah, because GWT not support java.text.Collator (and java.util.Locale also) ;/

Any solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this solution which uses javascript. This is because GWT doesn't support Collator.

http://osdir.com/ml/GoogleWebToolkit/2009-06/msg01572.html

```
public class Collator {

   public static final Collator getInstance() {
      return instance;
   }

   private static final Collator instance = new Collator();

   public native int compare( String source, String target ); /*-{
     return source.localeCompare( target );
   }-*/
}
```

I have never used it personally, but it looks promising. 
You might have to make changes so that there are no cross browser issues.

**Edit:**
Read up on JSNI.
This allows GWT to invoke raw "javascript" code within your Java code. This is what we are doing in the above class. The method "compare" makes a native call to javascript.
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#writing

Add Collator.java to your current work space.

You should be able to compare as follows.

```
Collator customCollator = Collator.getInstance();
if ( customCollator.compare( srcString , targetString ) > 0 )
{
     //the compare method will return an int.
     // write your code here.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I found it also but I don't know how to use it ;/

Comment: And new problem with JSNI: JS localeCompare() don't work great in Chrome.  LocaleCompare() also returns unexpected values in that it should only return 1, 0 ,-1 (in Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to add a locale property to the constants class.

I have a GeneralConstants class which is defined like so

```
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Constants;

public interface GeneralConstants extends Constants {

   @DefaultStringValue( "de" )
   String locale();
```

in every constants class I can inherit the locale and I can easily define it in every language

to know what locale I'm in. I just call the attribute

```
private static GeneralConstants c = GWT.create( GeneralConstants.class );
```

...

```
formData.getForm().getName( c.locale() )
```

there is also a way to get the currently set locales but I can't remember :-)

Comment: And how does this help you with string comparison?